# "durch [etwas] unverdorben"

Tags: meaning, sentence-structure

Im folgenden Satz:

> X ist durch Y unverdorben.

Ist Y der Grund, dass X unverdorben ist? Oder wurde X davor bewahrt, von Y verdorben zu werden?

*Beispiel*

> Barbara ist durch ihre Mutter unverdorben.

Heißt das:

> Barbara wurde nicht durch ihre Mutter verdorben.

oder

> Barbara wurde von ihrer Mutter davor bewahrt, verdorben zu werden.

?

Comment: Ob "durch" hier das richtige Adverb ist, müsste man diskutieren. Ich glaube das nämlich nicht.

Comment: @tofro Man wird doch *durch* einen Einfluss verdorben, bleibt also, wenn man ihm widerstehen kann, durch diesen *unverdorben*. Bsp.: "[Unsere Postordnung stellt die Bestimmung auf], daß die Post nur verpflichtet ist, den Empfängern die Gegenstände *äußerlich* unverletzt, durch äußere Einwirkungen unverdorben und nach dem Aufgabegewicht abzuliefern." Verhandlungen der Landes-Versammlung des Herzogthums Braunschweig 1863/64 (https://www.google.de/books/edition/Verhandlungen_der_Landes_Versammlung_des/mwVLAAAAcAAJ, bitte Suche im Buch benutzen)

Comment: Du musst beim Adverb zwischen Sachen und Menschen unterscheiden. Menschen werden *von* etwas verdorben.

Comment: @tofro Da muss dich dein Sprachgefühl trügen. In Google Books finde ich unzählige Belege dafür, dass Menschen *durch* etwas verdorben werden. Ernst Weiß: "Du hast mich durch deine Güte verdorben."

Comment: Das liegt daran, dass "verdorben" mehr als eine Bedeutung hat.

Comment: @tofro (1) Du hast behauptet, Menschen würden (ausschließlich) *von* etwas verdorben. Das ist falsch. (2) Die Bedeutung von *verderben* in "durch Güte verdorben" ist dieselbe wie in "durch ihre Mutter unverdorben", nämlich "auf jmdn. einen (bzw. keinen) moralisch schlechten Einfluss ausüben". Wenn man im einen Fall *durch* verwenden kann, kann man es demnach aus im anderen und dein anfängerlicher Einwand ist auch mit dem Hinweis auf eine mögliche unterschiedliche Bedeutung hinfällig.

Comment: @Ben, Sie verwechseln hier das Verb *verderben* mit dem Adjektiv *verdorben* und übetragen das dann auch noch auf *unverdorben*. Im Beispielsatz „*Du hast* mich durch deine Güte *verdorben*“ handelt es sich um ein Verb im Perfekt (*du verdirbst*, *du verdarbst*, *du hast verdorben*). Allerdings gibt es kein Verb *unverderben* (also so etwas wie *du unverdirbst jemand*). Im Beispielsatz „X *ist* durch Y *unverdorben*“ handelt es sich eindeutig um ein Adjektiv.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Die Bedeutung des Adjektives *verdorben* ergibt sich doch aus der Bedeutung des Verbes *verderben*. Es beschreibt den Zustand, der sich durch den Prozess ergibt, den das Verb beschreibt. Und *unverdorben* ist nur die Negation davon. Gewissermaßen das Ergebnis des Prozesses, wenn etwas *nicht verdorben* wird. Insofern verwechsele ich hier m.E. nichts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Das Interessante ist, daß mit *un-* präfigierte Adjektive Lesarten erlauben, in denen eine Phrase mit *von* oder *durch* als das Agens des zugrundeliegenden Verbs interpretiert wird (Belege von [DWDS Corpora](https://www.dwds.de/r)).

> Nur die Hälfte der Gesamtbevölkerung der Stadt würde sowohl unverletzt wie unberührt durch den radioaktiven Ausfall bleiben (siehe Bild 2). (*Archiv der Gegenwart* 37, 1967.)
>
> Das gäbe ihm zwei Jahre Zeit, unbehelligt von drängenden Gläubigern die wirre Finanzsituation des Konzerns zu bereinigen. (*Berliner Zeitung*, 23. 12. 2003)
>
> Alte Menschen schätzen die Ruhe, Kinder die Möglichkeit, ungefährdet von Hundehaufen, Müll und Scherben auch barfuß herumtoben zu können. (*Berliner Zeitung*, 30. 9. 1999)

Dadurch entsteht die eine Lesart von *Barbara ist durch die Mutter unverdorben*: Die Mutter hat Barbara nicht verdorben. In der anderen Lesart (die Mutter ist der Grund dafür, daß Barbara nicht verdorben ist) wird *durch* dagegen einfach als kausale Präposition verstanden.

Ich gehe davon aus, daß es nur darum ging, diese Mehrdeutigkeit herauszuarbeiten; es dürfte klar sein, daß die meisten Sprecher diese Gedanken anders ausdrücken würden (z.B. *ist nicht von ihrer Mutter verdorben worden*, *ist dank ihrer Mutter unverdorben*).

Comment: Danke für die grammatische Erklärung. Das ist aufschlussreich. –– Ja, richtig, es ging mir hier nur darum, ob die Konstruktion nur die eine oder nur die andere oder beide Lesarten zulässt. Ich war mir unsicher.

Comment: Was hat das mit Grammatik zu tun? Null. Das läuft üblicher Weise unter dem Stichwort Pragmatik, weil es insbesondere darauf ankäme, was man zu den Pflichten einer Mutter zählt. Wenn die Mutter also die Internetnutzung von Barbara nicht kontrolliert und sie sich so mir nichts dir nicht auf German SE Antworten gibt, dann ist "sie" eine Referenz auf Davids mittelmäßige Antwort, aber die Mutter, die ist so wie so schuldig, die gar keinen Einfluss darauf hat. Genauso käme es darauf an, ob die Aufzählung von Glasscherben usw. abschließend ist, ob die Gläubigiger und nicht etwa Finanzamt drängen ...

Comment: Allein im ersten der zitierten Beispiele ist eine definitive Aussage erkennbar, dass die andere Hälfte der Stadtbevölkerungen dem radioaktiven Ausfall ausgesetzt ist. Im zweiten ist noch erkennbar, dass der Finanzwirt nicht mit den Büchern der Gläubiger arbeitet. Im dritten gilt die subtile Unterstellung, dass man wohl doch besser Schuhe tragen möchte, wenngleich ein Partizip des Konjunktivs *können* vom Indikativ nicht unterscheidbar ist. Wäre *durch* etwa eine Konjunktion (oder was?) statt kausaler Präposition, müssten dafür Tests herhalten, \* Barabara wurde weil ihre Mutter, du weist schon

Answer (score 2):

Es kann beides heißen. Welche Interpretation zutrifft, muss sich aus dem Kontext ergeben. Wenn es um Verständnis und Präzision geht, bietet sich an, den Satz entsprechend Deiner Vorschläge umzuformulieren.

Das Hauptproblem der Formulierung ist, dass angenommen wird, dass Unverdorbenheit aktiv erreicht werden kann. Falls ich mir diesen Begriff zueigen machen müsste, würde er in meiner Vorstellungswelt etwas beschreiben, was nur aktiv zerstört werden kann (bspw. à priori dem Kinde angeboren ist), sodass die Unverdorbenheit zwar durch jemanden/etwas geschütz oder bewahrt werden kann, aber nicht durch jemanden/etwas vermittelt werden.

Analog zu "verdorben" kann sicher aber argumentieren, dass "durch" eher den Sinn kommuniziert *wodurch* die Unverdorbenheit selbst hervorgerufen wird (aber siehe oben) und der Vermittler oder Grund mit 'wegen' dargestellt wird:

> Marie ist wegen ihrer Mutter durch die Medien unverdorben.

Aber auch hier wäre die aktive formulierung besser:

> Marie ist wegen ihrer Mutter nicht durch die Medien verdorben.

Comment: Ja, die Doppeldeutigkeit ungeschickt. Danke, dass du mir geholfen hast, dass mir das deutlich geworden ist.

Answer (score 0):

Die Formulierung ist zunächst eine - sarkastische - Umkehrung einer Phrase, nämlich *durch etwas verdorben sein.* Bei dieser feststehenden Wendung ist klar, daß das genannte *Etwas* die Ursache der Verdorbenheit (oder Verderbtheit) darstellt. Beispielsweise:

> Er wurde durch den Erfolg verdorben.

Das kann etwa bedeuten, daß der Angesprochene aufgrund seines Erfolgs selbstherrlich, arrogant, von sich eingenommen, großsprecherisch oder sonstwas geworden ist, jedenfalls eine negative Eigenschaft entwickelt hat, die er - so die Implikation - möglicherweise ohne diesen Erfolg nicht entwickelt hätte und die er auch vor Eintreten des Erfolgs nicht hatte.

Daraus folgt, daß die gewendete Phrase *durch etwas unverdorben* mit dem *Etwas* die Sache bedeutet, der jemand entweder nicht ausgesetzt war oder die trotz ihrer potentiell abträglichen Wirkung dieselbe beim Betreffenden nicht gezeitigt hat. Beispielsweise:

> Er war durch Erfolg unverdorben.

Das kann entweder eine sarkastische Anspielung darauf sein, daß er noch nie auch nur in die Nähe eines Erfolgs gekommen ist oder, daß er zwar Erfolg hatte, aber die als häufig implizierten Begleiterscheinungen - siehe oben - eben nicht zeigt.

> Barbara ist durch ihre Mutter unverdorben.

Kann also - aber das festzustellen würde mehr Kontext erfordern - bedeuten, daß ihre Mutter als Erzieherin zwar eine Niete war, sich diese Defizienz aber bei Barbara nicht ausgewirkt hat oder, daß ihre Mutter sich nicht um ihre Erziehung gekümmert hat und deshalb quasi keine Gelegenheit hatte, bei Barbara etwas zu verderben.

Für die angedeutete positive Möglichkeit, nämlich daß ihre Mutter sie davor bewahrt hat, verdorben zu werden, ist die Formulierung insgesamt zu sarkastisch angelegt. Das sollte man - aber das ist eine Frage des Stils und damit meinungsgebunden - in meinen Augen anders ausdrücken.

Comment: Danke, dass du den sarkastischen (oder ironischen) Aspekt herausgearbeitet hast. Das war mir ganz entgangen! Und das ist äußerst hilfreich.